# Server not receiving message from client with correct IP and port opened

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, port, portforwarding

What can cause this to happen?

I moved my laptop to a friends house to work on this project.  I opened the same port on his xfinity router, and changed all areas of my code to his IP.  However it appears that the client is sending a message and the server has never getting past this part of code

```
System.out.println("running server!");
        int nreq = 1;
        try{
            //SET ME PORT
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(7332);
        for(;;){
            Socket newsock = sock.accept();
            System.out.println("Creating thread...");
            //Broken Old Login crap, needs reworked for map n stuff anyhow now
        //  Thread t = new ThreadHandler(newsock, nreq);
            Thread t = new RequestInterpreter(newsock, nreq);
            //t.run();
            t.start();
            nreq++;
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It never gets to print "Creating thread".  I'm not sure where to begin with what could be going wrong here?

The only thing that has changed is the house, IP, router, and internet.  Works everywhere else.   What about those changing  could block the client from sending a

Here is a test client I wrote also.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;




public class testClientConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting testConnection");
        try{            

        Socket s = new Socket("xx.xx.xx.xxx", 7332);        

        DataInputStream fromServer = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
        PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);    
        toServer.println("account name");
        toServer.println("password");
        toServer.println("Login");

        System.out.println("Sent message...");

        String response = fromServer.readLine().toString();
        //Toast the result here?  //testing

        System.out.println("response: " + response);
        if (response.equals("Login Success")) {

System.out.println("Login Success!!!");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){   /         
        }       
    }
}
```

HUGE UPDATE!

Ok so my client was an android phone and I turned the wifi off, so it fell onto 4g-LTE.  Then it worked.  So... Something is blocking the client side code.  What might that be?

Comment: From the 1.7 docs. [`ServerSocket.accept()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) *"Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method **blocks** until a connection is made."* suggests 'no connection is made'.

Comment: Alright so its probably not getting a connection.  But the client has the correct IP and port so what might be blocking that?

Comment: Note that 'blocks until' in that documentation actually means 'waits for' as opposed to 'denies or prevents'.  It is a little unclear (written in a vague language where every word means at least two things).  It seems the code is waiting for an incoming connection that never arrives (for whatever reason).

Comment: Yeah, so then it must be something which is blocking the client from sending the message.  Or a failure to receive.  So what could cause that?

Comment: `catch(Exception e){   / }` Huh?  That would not compile.  Please don't 'edit code by hand'.  Copy/paste the actual code & include a `printStackTrace` for every catch.

Comment: Oops sorry there was just a comment there which I failed to totally delete.  That's all

Comment: May be there is some configuration in the wifi router which prevents the connection

Answer (score 0):

The firewall on your friend's router is the usual suspect.
Second suspect is the firewall on the target machine.

Try disabling those.

Comment: Well if the firewall on my laptop has not needed configured at other locations I should assume it wouldn't need any changes here?  This is set to a "home network" like the others.

Comment: Not your firewall. The router's one. Or the target machine's one. And no it's not a good assumption that all routers are configured the same way.

Comment: I totally disabled the firewall on the router and it still won't work.

Comment: Where's the server? I don't get it from your description.

Comment: Make sure his ISP allows connections without a proxy. That's the third suspect.

Comment: Yeah I've disabled all firewalls everywhere at this point.   How can I find this out?  And assuming they do, what is the solution to that?

Comment: Try doing a `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25`. If it works you don't have a proxy. If you have a proxy you can't fix that. The ISP can allow an exception for you.

Comment: I hate to ask this but how do I use that?

Comment: On Windows you write that in a Command Prompt, on Mac/Linux in a Terminal window. No cryptic answer from the gmail server means it doesn't work.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have it installed by default anymore. You'll either have to install it or try writing a simple piece of code that tries to connect to `smtp.gmail.com:25` to check if it works.

Comment: Ok I enabled it and it sent me some message.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP qj8sm106........  So We're good on that front?

Comment: Yeah. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Update in main body.  Might change things

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be NAT on the router.

Servers don't work behind NAT devices unless you set up port-forwarding so that the router knows where to send an incoming request from outside.